# How to make a Query to write cell value based on content of another spreadsheet on GoogleSheets?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, excelquery

I've two spreadsheets and I want write the values of a column based on the values of another columns.

On the master spreadsheet I've two columns of interest: 'Ativo' and 'CNPJ'.

On the second spreadsheet called '`CNPJs`' I've the two columns called 'TICKER' and 'CNPJ'.

My goal é automatically fill the column 'CNPJ' of master spreadsheet based on the condition 'Ativo' = 'TICKER' on the '`CNPJs`' spreadsheet.

This is the master spreadsheet with the void column ready to be filled.
[image]

This is the CNPJs spreadsheet with the desired values of CNPJ field.

[image]

This is the query used and returning a error:

```
=QUERY(CNPJs!A2:B16; "select B2 where (CNPJs!A2 = A2)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `query` won't work as written.

It would usually be in this format:

`=QUERY(CNPJs!A:B;"select B where A matches 'xxx' ";0)`

but it won't evaluate down each row for `xxx`.

You're probably better with a `VLOOKUP` in an `ARRAYFORMULA` like this in cell `B2` of the master sheet:

`=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(A2:A;CNPJs!A:B;2;false);))`